# Unable to talk to Bruno very early in campaign

Tags: nazi-zombie-army

I'm running into what appears to be a bug: I can't talk to Bruno just a few minutes into a new campaign in the mission "Dead ahead," under the title "Reporting for duty." I can ring Bruno's bell, but there's no action to allow me to actually speak with him.

How can I advance from here?

[image: Screenshot]

I'm playing through Stadia Pro. Restarting from checkpoint or even restarting the game with a new campaign doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had reached out to Rebellion support and received the following response:

> This will be resolved in an upcoming patch.